# Tcl file content processing

Tags: tcl

I have a .csv file with below data

```
January,A1,100 
January,A2,200
January,A3,300
January,B1,100
January,B2,300
February,A1,100
February,A2,200
February,B2,200
March,C1,200
March,B1,400
April,D1,100
```

I need to read the above .csv file from disk, process it and display it's summary as below. How do I convert the above raw data into below values?

```
Month       A     B
January    600   400
February   300   200
March        0   400
April        0     0
```

The formula for A is total of values in index 2 when index 1 is A1/A2/A3(0 if not available)

The formula for B is total of values in index 2 when index 1 values is B1/B2/B3(0 if not available)

What I tried:

```
set file [open $loc r]
while {[gets $file sline] >=0} {
  regsub {"(.*?),(.*?)"} $sLine {\1:\2} sLine 
  set lsLine [split $sLine ","]
  set month [lindex $lsLine 0]
  lappend mnList $month
  set monthList [lsort -unique $mnList]
}
```

I did figure out the formating part with below code.

```
set Month $monthList 
set A {600 300 0 0}
set B {400 200 400 0}

set formatStr {%15s%15s%15s}
puts [format $formatStr "Month" "A" "B"]
foreach month $Month a $A b $B {
puts [format $formatStr $month $a $b]
}
```

I am having hard time calculating the values of A and B columns from the file. I tried multiple ways inside `foreach month $monthList` but none helped me to get the values I need :(

P.S. Pretty new to tcl and coding

Answer (score 1):

```
set file [open file.csv r]
set data {}
while {[gets $file line] != -1} {
    lassign [split $line ,] month key value
    dict update data $month monthData {
        dict incr monthData [string range $key 0 0] $value
    }
}
# $data contains:
# January {A 600 B 400} February {A 300 B 200} March {C 200 B 400} April {D 100}

proc dictGetDef {dictValue key default} {
    if {![dict exists $dictValue $key]} {
        return $default
    }
    return [dict get $dictValue $key]
}

dict for {month monthData} $data {
    puts [format {%-10s %5d %5d} $month [dictGetDef $monthData A 0] [dictGetDef $monthData B 0]]
}
```

```
January      600   400
February     300   200
March          0   400
April          0     0
```

Tcl 8.7 has [`dict getdef`](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.7/TclCmd/dict.html#M14) natively, but better.

---

To restrict the accumulating to a set of specific keys can be done is several ways. Using switch makes it quite explicit:

```
while {[gets $file line] != -1} {
    lassign [split $line ,] month key value
    switch -- $key {
        A1 - A2 - A3 -
        B1 - B2 - B3 {
            dict update data $month monthData {
                dict incr monthData [string range $key 0 0] $value
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You give [`switch`](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/switch.htm) pattern-body pairs. If the body is `-` then it falls through to the next body.

Comment: Hi, I  wanted help to calculate values of column A and B from the raw .csv file. I don't see that part in your answer. Sorry if I wasn't clear.

Comment: And that's what I showed. See the [`dict` man page](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/dict.htm) particularly the `update` and `incr` subcommands.

Comment: Thanks, I understood your code and it works. so, this groups the alphabets and sums the values.  What if there is January,A4,200 and I don't want to iclude A4 in the sum and only want A1, A2 and A3? Is there a way to make this work?